# System.IO.FileNotFoundException - cant create XML file in project folder

Tags: c#, winforms

I am doing a project in C# using Winforms, and I want to create a Podcast RSS reader. So I have a XmlSerializer that saves a podcast entity to a podcastlist and I should then get a podcast.xml file in my project files that it then reads ( I guess). I got it to do exactly that, but with adding Categories. But when I want to read a URL that contains a RSS-file, it wont Save(Serialize) it using the XmlReader. Ive been staring at this for most of the day and I cant just figure out whats going wrong.

Here is my serializer and saved list of Podcasts.

```
    protected string fileOfPodcasts = @"Podcasts.xml";
    public List<Podcast> listOfPodcasts = new List<Podcast>();

    public void SavePodcastList(List<Podcast> podcastList)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(podcastList.GetType());
        using (FileStream outFile = new FileStream(fileOfPodcasts, FileMode.Create,
            FileAccess.Write))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(outFile, podcastList);
        }
    }

    public List<Podcast> ReturnPodcasts()
    {
        List<Podcast> listOfPodcastsToBeReturned;
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Podcast>));
        using (FileStream inFile = new FileStream(fileOfPodcasts, FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read))
        {
            listOfPodcastsToBeReturned = (List<Podcast>)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(inFile);
        }
        return listOfPodcastsToBeReturned;
    }



    public void CreatePodcastObject ( string url, string interval, string category) // 3 parametrar
    {
        Podcast newPodcast = null;
        
        {
            newPodcast = new Podcast(url, interval, category); 
        }
        podcastRepository.Create(newPodcast);
    }

    public void Create(Podcast entity)
    {
        podcastList.Add(entity);
        SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Specify the full path of your file name, not just `"Podcasts.xml"`. Note that this is a quite broad topic. For example, when you deploy, if your app is installed in Program Files, there's a good chance that you cannot write there. You usually use the User `AppData/Local` or `AppData/Roaming` paths (in WinForms, `Application.LocalUserAppDataPath` and `Application.UserAppDataPath`) or the ProgramData folder (in WinForms, `Application.CommonAppDataPath`). Use Path.Combine to build the path: e.g., `Path.Combine(Application.CommonAppDataPath, "Podcasts.xml")`.

Comment: Note that, in any case, the app version is part of the path, so different versions of the same executable will create different folders, depending on the version of the assembly. -- Of curse you cannot write to the Project's Folder, that path won't exist when you deploy.